# transpose multiple datas in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have raw data containing the number of stores spread over numerous pages with no headers or columns.

Please sample below

[image]

I want to tranpose the data to this

[image]

Anyone who can help me figure out how to get the results I want?

Comment: Do not include images of data. They cannot be copied or edited. Please include the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, None, 1], 
                   "B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None], 
                   "C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8], 
                   "D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]}) 

index_ = ['Row_1', 'Row_2', 'Row_3', 'Row_4', 'Row_5']
df.index = index_
  
# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

[image: enter image will use DataFrame.transpose() here]

```
> # return the transpose result = df.transpose()   
> # Print the result print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).